# Would not this buffer reduce signal resolution for sensor driver? (recommended schematic)

Tags: operational-amplifier, driver, buffer, dual-supply, signal-conditioning

I am following [this design.](https://www.analog.com/media/en/reference-design-documentation/reference-designs/CN0288.pdf)

For my application, the LVDT driver would give me a +-10 V output.

Analog Devices recommeds a buffer for clearing the output signal of the driver. The thing is that they recommend a single supply op-amp (buffer) (5V-GND).

If I use that design, my output (from -10V to +10V) would be reduced to the possible buffer output (from GND to +5V.)  I think I need a dual supply (+-15V) high precision op-amp with rail to rail output, so the reference design does not work for my application. Am I wrong?

[image]

Comment: What voltage range can your ADC handle? Since it's supply is 5V, I guess it 0-5V? That may be one reason to have the 5V buffer. The other thing is what is the interested output voltage range of the sensor? Looks like they are interested only between 0-5V hence don't care about the clipping beyond that range

Comment: @sai That schematic is from the link above, the recommended reference design. My datalogger device can cope with +-15V inputs without problems

Comment: Providing -+10v into an ADC running off of 0-5v is a great way to damage an ADC. Limiting the supply rails to safe voltages is a nice safety feature.

Comment: @user1850479 My datalogging device can handle +-10, I need to find a dual supply buffer with +-10V output to transmit my signal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the ADC in the reference design is 0-5V, the buffer before it has 5V supply to limit the input to the ADC. If your ADC can handle higher voltage, you can use a dual supply buffer before the ADC. It seems the AD8615 cannot be used in that case because it can't handle those voltages as per the datasheet.

Answer (score 2):

The LVDT chip can be configured for unipolar or bipolar output.

The given schematic is fine for unipolar output.

If you chose bipolar output, then you can't use example for unipolar output.